# Register sharepoint site in azure B2C application setting

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure

My scenario is i have a sharepoint site that i want my b2c users to access using mfa,i was told to add sharepoint as an application on the B2C tenant, can anyone show me the steps, i tried [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration) but i dont know how to use it for sharepoint context